# How to add existing custom component to cq_dialog in AEM?

Tags: xml, dialog, components, aem

I'm new to AEM.

Let's say i got custom component that i want to include in xml cq_dialog and retrieve a value from `secondProp` that it has. How can i do this?

I've thought the annotation `sling:resourceType="my-aem/components/custom-component"` added to `secondProp` will do it but apparently not.

Cq_dialog:

```
... 
  
  
<items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <title
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
                                                fieldLabel="Title"
                                                name="./title"
                                                required="{Boolean}true"
                                        />
    <secondProp
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                sling:resourceType="my-aem/components/custom-component"
                                                fieldLabel="secondProp"
                                                name="./secondProp"
                                                required="{Boolean}true"
                                        />
...
```